# How to do error logging when Play 2.1 crashes on startup

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I have a Play 2.1 application which does not start when I have the wrong database url. The problem is, the error message isn't that great.

```
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for    0ms and trying again. A  ttempts left: 0. Exception: null
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:74)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:552)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:248)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:239)
....
```

I'd like the server to dump the database url it's trying to use in this case. Does Play 2.1 provide any hooks to execute code when there is an exception during startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Play Framework 2, you can override certain phases of the lifecycle by extending `GlobalSettings`. Specifically, `onLoadConfig` get called before the config is parsed and the DB connection is established.

Here's a (hacky) example of intercepting errors. You can create a fake instance of `Application`, then pass it the `Configuration` object. Then you can use it to create an instance of `BoneCPPlugin` and try creating a connection. In case when the DB is not reachable, you'll be able to intercept that in the catch block.

```
import java.io.File
import play.api._
import play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode) = {
    val app = new DefaultApplication(path, classloader, None, mode){
        override lazy val configuration = config
    }
    try {
        new BoneCPPlugin(app).onStart()
    } catch {
        case e: PlayException =>
            // handle
        case _ => // other types of errors that we don't care about here
    }
    super.onLoadConfig(config, path, classloader, mode)
  }
}
```

Comment: With this approach you are "test starting" an application and a database connection pool before starting the actual application, is that right? Sort of kicking the tires before you get in the car? Seems like a lot of extra processing, but I suppose it is only at startup.